# QFileDialog: Open multiple and/or nonexisting files

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

In python/pyQt, with a `QFileDialog`, one can very easily use one of the four static methods to create a dialog:

```
getOpenFileName()
getOpenFileNames()  # Accepts multiple files
getSaveFileName()   # You can provide either a new file or "overwrite" an existing one
getExistingDirectory()
```

I marked the ones of patricular interest to me. What I am trying to achieve is a dialog that lets me select one or more than one existing files (like getOpenFileNames()) and/or a nonexisting one (like getSaveFileName()).

I already managed to get rid of the confirm overwrite popup by applying options:

```
QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'inFile', self.lastpath, options=QtGui.QFileDialog.DontConfirmOverwrite)
```

which lets me select any file or a new file, but *only one*.
I also tried not using the static methods but creating an object:

```
dlg = QtGui.QFileDialog( None )
dlg.setWindowTitle( 'File for trjFile' )
dlg.setViewMode( QtGui.QFileDialog.Detail )
dlg.setFileMode( QtGui.QFileDialog.AnyFile )
dlg.setAcceptMode ( QtGui.QFileDialog.AcceptOpen )
dlg.setConfirmOverwrite( False )
```

but when setting the FileMode, I'm looking for a combination of `AnyFile` and `ExistingFiles` (see [the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum)).

Is there any way to achive this, or am I better off creating my own FileDialog?

**Background**:
I am creating code for a UI by parsing an HTML - which only tells me, that the variable type needed is a "Path" - no information about whether this path will be read or written to, or how many files may be specified.